# Multiple breakpoints for one line of code in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have the following setup: A C# Application that references a managed c++ DLL.  The managed C++ DLL links in an un-managed C++ static library.

I have 2 questions:
1) I can not set an active break point in the Managed C++ DLL even though I can step into it.

2) I can set a break point in the un-managed C++ library but it will not be hit until I clear it and put it back.  Also, in VS the break point shows up as two entries on the same line of code.  When it hits only one hits and not the other.  Its like there are two instructions loaded but with identical code.  There is a plus button next to the break point and if clicked it expands to two lines.

[image]

When I try to move the cursor to a diffrent line of code off the breakpoint I get the following window:

[image]

Reinforcing the idea that there are multiple instructions loaded.

Any help on how to resolve either of theses issues would be greatly appreciated.